# Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: syntax error at or near "INCLUDE"

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I m working  with PostgresSql & EF core 3.1. I created an index for one of my entity as follow

```
builder.HasIndex(e => e.MerchantId).IncludeProperties(e=>e.TemplateType);
```

in migration file i can see the below

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_EmailTemplates_MerchantId",
                table: "EmailTemplates",
                column: "MerchantId")
                .Annotation("Npgsql:IndexInclude", new[] { "TemplateType" });
```

When run update-database I m getting the below Error.

```
Failed executing DbCommand (24ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE INDEX "IX_EmailTemplates_MerchantId" ON "EmailTemplates" ("MerchantId") INCLUDE ("TemplateType");
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (24ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX "IX_EmailTemplates_MerchantId" ON "EmailTemplates" ("MerchantId") INCLUDE ("TemplateType");
**Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: syntax error at or near "INCLUDE"**
```

Any one can help me on this error ?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? The `include` option was added in Postgres 11

Comment: hi @a_horse_with_no_name.Thanks for your reply. i found this version PostgreSQL 9.5.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit

Comment: Then you will need to upgrade. (9.5 is going to be EOL in 6 months anyway)

Comment: hi @a_horse_with_no_name , Thanks. I ll update the postgres to latest